# How to convert european date format to Date Object in react native and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Given a date such as November 23, 2021 in this European format: 23/11/2021. I try converting it to a date object like this:

```
const dateString =  '23/11/2021'
const dateObj = new Date(dateString)
```

However, this is giving me an error saying this is an invalid date. I don't want to just convert it to the US date format, since I am trying to see if I can sort the dates given the European format. Anyone know how I can convert this to a date object given the european date format?

Comment: You could do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982583/2030565

Answer (score 2):

If the format is always **dd.MM.yyyy** it can be done by slicing the date string to get the year, month and day required to create the Date object.

```js
const date =  '23/11/2021'

const d = date.slice(0,2),
      m = date.slice(3,5),
      y = date.slice(6,10);

const dateObj = new Date(y, m, d)

console.log(dateObj)
```

Comment: Need to subtract 1 from `m` due to January being 0

Comment: @ImperfectClone then you can replace `m = date.slice(3,5)` with `m = Number(date.slice(3,5)) - 1`.. does that help ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the edit I was suggesting. The answer is helpful, but the result is off by one month at the moment